# MySQL: Grabbing the latest ID from duplicate records within a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to grab the latest ID from a duplicate record within my table, without using a timestamp to check.

```
SELECT *
FROM    `table`
WHERE   `title` = "bananas"
```

-

```
table
id title
-- -----
1  bananas
2  apples
3  bananas
```

Ideally, I want to grab the ID `3`

Comment: How do you define "latest id"? Just the largest one? What do you mean by "duplicate records"?

Comment: The largest id, as in the newest one created from the primary key. By duplicate records I mean duplicate titles in this case "bananas"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by the SELECT in your example, but hopefully you will be able to piece this out from my example.

If you want to return the latest row, you can simply use a [MAX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) function

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE
```

Though I definitely recommend trying to determine what makes that row the "latest". If its just because it has the highest column [id], you may want to consider what happens down the road. What if you want to combine two databases that use the same data?  Going off the [id] column might not be the best decision. If you can, I suggest an [LastUpdated] or [Added] datestamp column to your design.

Comment: This does not seem to address the "duplicate" portion of the question.

Comment: The bananas are the duplicated rows.  Since I assumed the table is auto incrementing the rows, the id with the highest value should be the last entered entry.

Comment: it was not clear to me. So the user already know that "banana" is indeed the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

im assuming the id's are autoincremented,

you can count how many rows you have, store that in a variable and then set the WHERE= clause to check for said variable that stores how many rows you have.

BUT this is a hack solution because if you delete a row and the ID is not decremented you can end up skipping an id.

Comment: The number of rows and the largest ID potentially have nothing to do with one another once a row is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select max(a.id) from mydb.myTable a join mydb.myTable b on a.id <> b.id and a.title=b.title;
```